# Tests for goodness of fit of Logit model

Tags: goodness-of-fit, logit, deviance

I'm performing a Logit regression and want to check the goodness of fit. I implemented two tests. First is check deviance. I compute the p-value as
$$
p = 1-\chi^2 (D,df)
$$
The second test I performed is Hosmer-Lemeshow test.

However, the first test reports p-value extremely closed to zero, while the second test gives p-value = 0.4. As far as I understand, Deviance test rejects the model, while Hosmer-Lemeshow test finds no evidence of bad fit.

Is it weird that two different tests return extremely different conclusion? Or, I misunderstand their function and compute the wrong things?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the code I use.

```
fit <- glm(y ~ formula, family = "binomial", 
             data = df)

# Perform Deviance Test of Fitness (compute p-value)
d.pvalue[i] <- 1 - pchisq(fit.t$deviance, fit.t$df.residual)

# Fitness Check of the models (compute p-value)
h1 <- hoslem.test(fit$y,fitted(fit))
```

Comment: Can you supply the output?  Are you looking at  the null deviance by any chance instead of the residual deviance?

Comment: @StatsStudent Thanks for replying.     
Null deviance: 109966  on 80176  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 106874  on 80173  degrees of freedom
AIC: 106882. I used residual deviance. (The data has about 80000 observations)